# Why is Rsync copying the same subset of (unchanged) files every time?

Tags: backup, rsync

I am backuping files on my machine with rsync, but notice in my log files that a small subset of the files are re-synced each and every time. Why is this happening?

(I can understand that those .AppleDoubles may change from time to time, but the pictures and movie files are old and should not have changed.)

My rsync command is

```
rsync -av --delete --log-file=Logfile.log --rsync-path='sudo rsync' fromfolder tofolder
```

and the Logfile keeps turning up with

```
2014/11/25 17:08:27 [11866] receiving file list
2014/11/25 17:08:29 [11868] >f.st....... Foto/2007/DSC_3646.JPG
2014/11/25 17:08:29 [11868] >f.st....... Foto/2007/DSC_5333.JPG
2014/11/25 17:08:30 [11868] >f.st....... Foto/2007/DSC_5791.JPG
2014/11/25 17:08:30 [11868] >f.st....... Foto/2007/DSC_6005.JPG
2014/11/25 17:08:30 [11868] >f.st....... Foto/2007/DSC_6743.JPG
2014/11/25 17:08:31 [11868] >f.st....... Foto/2007/R1.JPG
2014/11/25 17:08:31 [11868] >f.st....... Foto/2007/R2.JPG
2014/11/25 17:08:31 [11868] >f..t....... Foto/2007/.AppleDouble/DSC_3646.JPG
2014/11/25 17:08:31 [11868] >f..t....... Foto/2007/.AppleDouble/DSC_5791.JPG
2014/11/25 17:08:31 [11868] >f..t....... Foto/2007/.AppleDouble/DSC_6743.JPG
2014/11/25 17:08:31 [11868] >f..t....... Foto/2007/.AppleDouble/R1.JPG
2014/11/25 17:08:31 [11868] >f..t....... Foto/2007/.AppleDouble/R2.JPG
2014/11/25 17:08:31 [11868] >f.st....... Foto/2007/L1000503.JPG
2014/11/25 17:08:32 [11868] >f..t....... Foto/2008/.AppleDouble/L1000503.JPG
2014/11/25 17:08:43 [11868] >f.st....... Multimedia/B.MOV
2014/11/25 17:08:43 [11868] >f..t....... Multimedia/.AppleDouble/B.MOV
2014/11/25 17:08:44 [11868] sent 105,561 bytes  received 80,878,709 bytes  3,446,139.15 bytes/sec
2014/11/25 17:08:44 [11868] total size is 177,280,586,662  speedup is 2,189.07
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A closer study has revealed the root cause of my problem: the receiving file system was not case-sensitive, and the files in question all had identical names in all but the extension, like this:

```
2873603 Oct 20  2009 R1.JPG
2180728 Oct 20  2009 R1.jpg
2814276 Oct 20  2009 R2.JPG
3150011 Oct 20  2009 R2.jpg
```

There seems to be a [working general solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11824856) to the problem, but since I only had a few files to change, I did a manual name-modification job on them. An voila, problem solved.

Comment: Aw, fix that destination filesystem then :D Perhaps the `--fuzzy` option will also help here since the file sizes are identical.

Comment: Indeed ;-) But in this case the files were not identical in size (actually it was red-eye removal going on in there).

Answer (score 2):

In the default mode of operation `rsync` uses the modification time as key to determine whether a file should be transferred or not. From its manual page:

> Rsync  finds  files  that  need to be transferred using a "quick
>   check" algorithm (by default) that looks for files that have changed
>   in size or in last-modified time.

Using the `--checksums` option, it will look at the file contents instead:

```
-c, --checksum              skip based on checksum, not mod-time & size
```

Comment: I see, I will definitely try that option out tomorrow. But what I do not get is still how that could be the root cause, since there are several thousand files in that folder, and only a small subset of files are copied each time, the rest are behaving like I want them to: being copied only when they are not actually already present in 'tofolder'

Comment: I encountered similar issues when syncing from my phone, or to an external disk. Is the filesystem always unmounted normally? If you remove the drive early, it is possible that not everything is written to disk. Oh, another possibility is hardware failure (bad sectors, bad RAM). By the way, you can use `--exclude='**/.AppleDouble/'` to ignore that directory.

Comment: Thanks for the exclude-tip: I have been too lazy to include any exclusions, but now I actually set up a exclusion file, taking care of these irritating 'help files' clogging upp log files. Unfortunately, the only thing happening with the -c option was that everything was slowed down considerably, but the files were still being transferred (in fact, the process is not yet terminated, although it has been an hour after it transferred the last of the usual suspects.

Comment: PS: It took 1h20m for the -c rsync process to finish after it had copied the last (unnecessary) file. Is that really normal behaviour?

Comment: @NickTheSwede The `-c` option must obtain a checksum of a file so it has to read the full file rather than just look at the size and date. Perhaps you could combine it with the mtime/size comparison, have a look at the manual page. Are you really sure that the files are not modified? What happens if you run the command twice in a row?

Comment: With my 'renaming solution' above, nothing is copied when I run the sync the second time. So it seems as the problem was indeed the (lack of) case-sensitivity